# Show that $N$ is orthcenter of triangle $AYZ$

Tags: geometry

Triangle $ABC$ has height $BE,CF$.$M$ is the midpoint of $BC$. $EF$ and AM intersects at point $N$. Draw $NX\perp BC, XY\perp AB, XZ\perp AC(X\in BC, Y\in AB, Z\in AC)$.Show that $N$ is orthcenter of triangle $AYZ$.

I can't find any lemma to solve this problem. How we draw any another geometry element to solve.Show me pls! [image]

Comment: Can you attach a picture?

Comment: I have added the picture. Pls show me this problem

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Help me pls. I don't know where it is

Answer (score 3):

[image]
First note that $\triangle AEF$ and $\triangle ABC$ are similar. Let $P$ be the midpoint of $EF$, then $$\angle APE = \angle AMB\tag{1}.$$
Moreover, $E,F$ lie on the circle with center $M$ and diameter $BC$, so $MP\perp EF$. So $MNPX$ is circular. It follows that 
$$\angle NPX + \angle AMB = 180^\circ.\tag{2}$$
From (1) and (2) we conclude that $A,P,X$ are colinear. Consequently, 
$$\frac{BX}{XC} = \frac{NE}{NF}.\tag{3}$$
Since $XZ\parallel BE$, we have $EZ : ZC = BX:XC = NE:NF$. Thus $NZ\parallel CF$, and similarly $NY \parallel BE$ and we are done.

---

Note: (3) may be a little subtle but I leave it to you to clarify.

Comment: Your solution is nice. But it lacks proper explanation. Might be not so good for newbies. You jumped to so many conclusions.